# Setting up a fund screening strategy

Tags: r, performance, finance, quantmod, performanceanalytics

I wonder if some of you guys have been applying some kind of analysis/screening when you choose which funds (hedge funds or other funds) you are going to invest your money in?
If you are, so what criterios do you use, or do you even have some example code?

I am thinking about to use `quantmod` library and `PerformanceAnalytics` library. And of course some other libraries too...

Greatful for any comments/guidelines!

Best Regards!

Comment: This question is far too broad...

Answer (score 4):

I think the function you are looking for is `sample`.  For example, if `funds` is a list of fund names:

```
> funds<-LETTERS[1:10]
> funds
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
```

Then `sample(funds)` will give you a pretty good strategy to choose which funds to invest in:

```
> sample(funds,5)
[1] "G" "A" "F" "C" "J"
```

If you want to get more sophisticated, then you could allocate a portion of your money to each fund.  In this case, the function `runif` is probably a good one.  Something like this:

```
> data.frame(fund=funds,allocation={x<-runif(10);x/sum(x)})
   fund  allocation
1     A 0.139513790
2     B 0.156152098
3     C 0.048013319
4     D 0.163331697
5     E 0.123784522
6     F 0.116643687
7     G 0.008980385
8     H 0.067164346
9     I 0.081205814
10    J 0.095210342
```

Disclaimer: taking investment advice from the internet is not usually a good idea!

Comment: LOL. Actually not a bad idea!